# Display an ALT tag that is not empty

Tags: tags, display, alt

We had some functions.php added to custom display a category image and its ALT tag, only it doesn't.
Can't contact the dev on this. It is a simple one, but I don't seem to be able to find it.

`add_action etc.

```
    if ( $image ) {
        
        echo '<img src="' . $image . '" alt="' . $alt . '" />';     ///THE image displays not the alt///
    }
}
```

}`
As mentioned the image displays but not the alt tag. I am not sure of the tag variable to use but $alt is wrong.
Any suggestions as to how to get the alt showing other than alt="" ?

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions on this. I hhave looked for info on similar queries but can't see anything that fits my bill.

Comment: Further research / testing.

Comment: info. 'code' if ( is_product_category() || is_woocommerce() ){
     global $wp_query;
     $cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
     $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
     $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );     
  $image_alt = get_the_title( $image->id );  
     if ( $image ) {
      echo '<img src="' . $image . '" alt="' . $image_alt . '" />';(NEARLY works, is a list of product images on the page in the category, instead of seeing category ALT, the first product in the tables alt is shown) 
  }
 }
}'code'